# CodeIgniter query in associative array

Tags: codeigniter

Please tell me how to pass OR condition in CodeIgniter query. My query like:

```
$where=array('status' => 'pending','linux_added_on >='=>$from_date,'linux_added_on <='=>$to_date);
```

And I want to add:

```
$where=array('status' => 'pending OR Approve','linux_added_on >='=>$from_date,'linux_added_on <='=>$to_date);
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Change query to your needs:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?"; 

$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));
```

The question marks in the query are automatically replaced with the values in the array in the second parameter of the query function.